# Div's width is ignored

Tags: html, css

I've tried re-using some method showing custom alert on a web page. For some reason the code works properly on old pages but not on my new one.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zgx0668/8/)

```css
.noPopup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.noPopup .np1 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.noPopup .np1:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}
.noPopup .np2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.noPopup .np4 {
  position: relative;
}
.noPopup .noPclose {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.noPopup .nt1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 25px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
.noPopup .nt2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 110px;
  top: 23px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
.noPopup .nt22 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 23px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
.noPopup .ndel {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 95px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #9f7709;
  width: 2px;
  height: 25px;
}
.noPopup .ndel2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 95px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #9f7709;
  width: 2px;
  height: 25px;
}
.noPopup .btnl {
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/btnl.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 120px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.noPopup .btnr {
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/btnr.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 80px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.noPopup .btnClose {
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/btnClose.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.noPopup .n123 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  width: 100%;
}
.noPopup .n789 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%;
}
.noPopup .nc2 {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border: solid 1px #9f7709;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.noPopup .nc22 {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border: solid 1px #9f7709;
  /*display: table-cell;
              vertical-align: middle;*/
}
.noPopup .nc23 {
  padding: 2px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.noPopup .nc2if {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border: solid 1px #9f7709;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
.noPopup .nc2im {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
.noPopup .nc {
  color: white;
  margin: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/gex.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left -60px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.noPopup .n1 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/1.png');
  float: left;
}
.noPopup .n2 {
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/2.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center 2px;
}
.noPopup .n3 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/3.png');
  float: right;
}
.noPopup .n7 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/7.png');
  float: left;
}
.noPopup .n8 {
  height: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/8.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.noPopup .n9 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/9.png');
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="noPopup" style="z-index:101;width:800px;height:0%;top:200px;left:74px">
    <div class="np1">
      <div class="np2">
        <div class="noPclose"></div>
        <div class="np4">
          <div class="btnClose" onclick="destroyLastMessage();"></div>
          <div style="left:24px" class="nt1">Title</div>
          <div class="nt22"></div>
          <div class="ndel"></div>
          <div class="n123">
            <div class="n1"></div>
            <div class="n3"></div>
            <div class="n2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="n789">
            <div class="n7"></div>
            <div class="n9"></div>
            <div class="n8"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="nc">
            <div style="text-align:left">
              Text
              <br>
              <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="100%" align="right"><span onclick="remindPassword(document.getElementById('txtForgotPasswordName').value)" class="button">Button</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is:

Although `div`'s `width` is set to 800px, it's being ignored.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please follow Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all this answers just say `do this` and **don't explain anything**.

the issue is you are using `inline-block` in child `.np2` which won't have any `width` by default, so either:

- you remove the `display:inline-block` (which will get it back to default display:block) and then this  have `width`

or

- you can just set some `width` on that `.np2`

---

**Note**: Don't use inline styles

```css
.noPopup {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 101;
  width: 800px;
 /* top: 200px;*/
  left: 74px
}
.noPopup .np1 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.noPopup .np1:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}
.noPopup .np2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%
}
.noPopup .np4 {
  position: relative;
}
.noPopup .noPclose {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.noPopup .nt1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 25px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
.noPopup .nt2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 110px;
  top: 23px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
.noPopup .nt22 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 23px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
.noPopup .ndel {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 95px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #9f7709;
  width: 2px;
  height: 25px;
}
.noPopup .ndel2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 95px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #9f7709;
  width: 2px;
  height: 25px;
}
.noPopup .btnl {
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/btnl.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 120px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.noPopup .btnr {
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/btnr.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 80px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.noPopup .btnClose {
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/btnClose.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.noPopup .n123 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  width: 100%;
}
.noPopup .n789 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%;
}
.noPopup .nc2 {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border: solid 1px #9f7709;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.noPopup .nc22 {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border: solid 1px #9f7709;
  /*display: table-cell;
              vertical-align: middle;*/
}
.noPopup .nc23 {
  padding: 2px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.noPopup .nc2if {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border: solid 1px #9f7709;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
.noPopup .nc2im {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
.noPopup .nc {
  color: white;
  margin: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/gex.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left -60px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.noPopup .n1 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/1.png');
  float: left;
}
.noPopup .n2 {
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/2.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center 2px;
}
.noPopup .n3 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/3.png');
  float: right;
}
.noPopup .n7 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/7.png');
  float: left;
}
.noPopup .n8 {
  height: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/8.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.noPopup .n9 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url('../Images/noPopup/9.png');
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="noPopup">
    <div class="np1">
      <div class="np2">
        <div class="noPclose"></div>
        <div class="np4">
          <div class="btnClose" onclick="destroyLastMessage();"></div>
          <div style="left:24px" class="nt1">Title</div>
          <div class="nt22"></div>
          <div class="ndel"></div>
          <div class="n123">
            <div class="n1"></div>
            <div class="n3"></div>
            <div class="n2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="n789">
            <div class="n7"></div>
            <div class="n9"></div>
            <div class="n8"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="nc">
            <div style="text-align:left">
              Text
              <br>
              <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="100%" align="right"><span onclick="remindPassword(document.getElementById('txtForgotPasswordName').value)" class="button">Button</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did it.

Answer (score 4):

Please remove `.noPopup .np2 { display: inline-block: }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the CSS of the class `.noPopup .np2` to be `display:block;` instead of `display:inline-block;`

```
.noPopup .np2 {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zgx0668/9/)

Comment: removing inline-block will get to the default block., so using it again, doesn't make sense in this case :)